# Vertex Coloring After Parenting in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine

I am trying to use a python script during runtime of bge to vertex color a mesh. The idea is to click the mouse and vertex color a mesh (the color is not uniform so I can't use object color). A simple version of the code is below and can be illustrated on the standard cube. Put in a logic brick for a mouse left button click and call it "click" along with a python controller running to this script.

```
cont=bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own=cont.owner
mesh=own.meshes[0]
click=cont.sensors["click"]
if click.positive:
    vertex=mesh.getVertex(0,1)
    vertex.color=[1,0,0,1]
```

This setup will color one vertex red. However when I parent the object to an armature (single bone) the code fails to do anything to the mesh.

If anyone can tell me where I am wrong or what I can do to achieve the end result in another way please let me know.

Comment: I believe this may be an error in the base code. Does anyone know where the C/C++/Python code that would control color rendering in bge is in the blender base code?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cont=bge.logic.getCurrentController()
> own=cont.owner
> mesh=own.meshes[0]
> click=cont.sensors["click"]
> if click.positive:
>     vertex=mesh.getVertex(0,1)
>     vertex.color=[1,0,0,1]
> ```

This code has no relation to a parent of the (controller owning) object. So this should never be an issue.

I can only guess you execute this code at the armature. An armature has no mesh and will fail when you try to access it (line 3).

*Hint*: When using code you should always have a console window open to see any error messages. If you already have ... please post error messages together with your question.

Comment: I have the logic bricks set on the mesh. I opened the console window and get no errors. I even tried printing the vertex colors before and after and they all come out correct. I spent some time debugging it until I got down to just the parenting step. I go from functional to no effect by just doing the parenting.

Comment: I just replicated this from a basic blender window on the basic cube in about 5 minutes in case someone wants to verify the problem.